# Vim with R-plugin and LaTeX-Suite results in backslash in insert mode misbehaving

Tags: r, vim, latex

Here's what happens. I'm using Vim + LaTeX-Suite to edit TeX files in Vim. This could be in the Terminal or in MacVim.

I happily

```
Insert lots of $\LaTeX \commands$ etc. I love using the $\backslash$.
```

TeX works great. No problem.

Then I go and open up a .R file in the same window (different tab). R-Plugin for Vim uses the `<Leader>` key (mapped to `\` as per usual) to execute commands, e.g. I type `\sa` to send the selection to R and execute and move the window down. Life is nice.

Problem: even though while editing an R file, Vim is nice enough not to bug me in insert mode when I type `\`, for some reason when I switch back to the tab to edit the TeX file, then type `\` in insert mode, it moves the cursor *left* of the `\` and pauses as though waiting for the rest of the command, before then re-moving to the right of the `\` and moving on as I type.

Below shows what happens *just* from typing `\` in insert mode; obviously I could reproduce this by moving the cursor to the left with the arrow keys, but that's not how this happened--the cursor just moves left for a split second as though waiting for the R command to finish being input.

[image]

So: how can I stop the annoying behavior in the TeX file insert mode, without sacrificing other functionality? Note, (a) I don't expect mapping `<Leader>` to a different key to help since then that key will just have the same left-cursor-move problem in TeX; (b), I like the leader as `\` anyway so I don't want to change it.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't launching two VIM sessions?  I think VIM loads plugins into the session and not into a global application state, so you could theoretically load the R files separately to prevent this issue.

Comment: Well, you are correct, that does work. But, I lose the joy of having all my tabs in one window....

Comment: Hmm come to think of it you raise an interesting point about the plugin behavior; either the R-plugin must be at work on the TeX-file, or ok, I just tested, and it turns out that once activated the R-plugin wreaks havoc period, irrespective of the file type. This is good information; thanks!

Comment: Eh, not exactly an answer here, but a general hint for vim guys. Have you realized R Studio's got a vim editing mode. I am not a vim geek but I love it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this line in your vimrc (requires Vim-R-plugin >= 0.9.9.2):

```
let g:vimrplugin_insert_mode_cmds = 0
```

If the problem persists, you can do the following in Normal mode to know what are the keyboard shortcuts in Insert mode:

:imap

Comment: Turns out I already had that in vimrc (maybe I tried to fix this before and forgot??) and therefore updating to 0.9.9.2 seems to have eliminated the problem. I'm going to keep playing with it for a couple of days and then award the bounty if it doesn't resurface. Thanks!